# Excluded Setup Project duplicate detected dependencies are included again

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dependencies, setup-project

We are encountering the following issue using Visual Studio 2008 wherein even when you save the setup project after setting the Exclude settings of duplicated detected dependencies to true, once you reload the project, the Exclude settings change back to false.

And because of this, you have to exclude the detected dependencies again to get the desired output.  We have a huge solution of interdependent 120+ projects with a vast number of dll dependencies, so it's a pain to change the values back.

I just simplified the scenario below (an understatement) to illustrate:

**PROJECTS:**

- PROJECTA - references DLL1, DLL2, DLL3
- PROJECTB - references DLL3, DLL4, PROJECTA
- PROJECTC - references DLL2, DLL3, DLL4
- PROJECT1 (Setup Project)

  - Primary output for PROJECTA (manually added)
  - Primary output for PROJECTB (manually added)
  - (detected dependencies automatically added by VS)

    - PROJECTA (set Exclude=True, value stays the same after reload)
    - DLL1 (set Exclude=True, value stays the same after reload)
    - DLL2 (set Exclude=True, value changes back to False after reload)
    - DLL2 (set Exclude=True, value changes back to False after reload)
    - DLL3 (no change, want to include)
    - DLL3 (set Exclude=True, value changes back to False after reload)
    - DLL3 (set Exclude=True, value changes back to False after reload)
    - DLL4 (set Exclude=True, value changes back to False after reload)
    - DLL4 (set Exclude=True, value changes back to False after reload)

**OUTPUT (for PROJECT1.msi):**

- Desired Output:

  - PROJECTA.dll
  - PROJECTB.dll
  - DLL3
- Output when VS changes the Exclude settings back to False:

  - PROJECTA.dll
  - PROJECTB.dll
  - DLL2
  - DLL3
  - DLL4

This will cause issues at runtime (plus a bloated installer).

I browsed the web and did not find a workable solution for our setup yet.  And some of the questions has been asked in the past, so I'm wondering if there is already a patch for this, or somebody has a new workaround that would help us.

Aside from using WIX and setting the Copy Local setting value of all the dependencies to false, does anybody has a solution to make Visual Studio keep the Exclude setting value?